# Adicionar checkbox a uma JTree

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtree

Já procurei bastantes exemplos por aí de `JTree`s com checkboxes mas parece-me tudo muito complexo.

Alguém sabe uma maneira simples, se é que existe, de adicionar a uma `JTree` que arrastei para o meu frame, uma checkbox em cada um dos nodes?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pretendia era por uma checkbox em cada um dos nodes, não estou muito por dentro do funcionamento das trees, era checkboxes em todos os items da imagem, menos no primeiro.

Comment: numa pesquisa rápida, encontrei vários exemplos mas nenhum deles parecem propriamente fáceis... Contudo este exemplo parece exactamente o que tu queres, vê se consegues adaptar para o teu caso *Link:* http://stackoverflow.com/a/12870909/3792998

Comment: Eu utilizei este http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jtree_with_checkboxes